# destroying a label in different frame python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to make an application with tkinter that shows different frames in same window and you go into these frames with a button, i ran into a problem, when you click the button it does what is supposed to do, but there is a gap in the middle, that is the label that is invisible, how do i change the widgets to only one frame and then call it by button and update that frame on the window. i hope i made my task clear, any help would do. here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

app1 = tk.Frame(app)
app1.grid()

app2 = tk.Frame(app)
app2.grid()

app3 = tk.Frame(app)
app3.grid()

text1 = tk.Label(app1, text="Home")
text1.grid()

text2 = tk.Label(app2, text="Home2")

app3.test = True
app3_label = tk.Label(app3, text="app3")
app3_label.grid()

app4 = tk.Frame(app)

app4.test = False
app4_label = tk.Label(app4, text="app4")
app4_label.grid()

def toggle():
    if(app3.test):
        app3.test = False
        app3.grid_forget()
        app4.test = True
        app4.grid()
        text2.grid()
    else:
        app4.test = False
        app4.grid_forget()
        app3.test = True
        app3.grid()
        text2.grid_forget()

button1 = tk.Button(app1, text="click", command=toggle)
button1.grid(row=0, column=2)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not using `grid()` properly. Grid needs to know the row and column if you want things to be in the correct order all the time. Without supplying `grid()` with row/column it will just apply to the next available row. Then when you use grid_forget() and then use grid() again it keeps that new row and is always on the next row when it should not be.
2. "that is the label that is invisible". This is not correct. The label has been removed with `grid_forget()` its not just invisible. The reason for that gap is once you removed the widget the frame kept its format.
3. You are making things more complicated than they need to be in the toggle function. This is no need for multiple true/false variables here and you should be using grid_forget() on the frames not the widgets in the frames.

Try this instead:

```
import tkinter as tk


app = tk.Tk()

toggle = False
app1 = tk.Frame(app)
app2 = tk.Frame(app)
app3 = tk.Frame(app)
app4 = tk.Frame(app)
app1.grid()
app2.grid()
app3.grid()

tk.Label(app1, text="Home").grid()
tk.Label(app2, text="Home2").grid()
tk.Label(app3, text="app3").grid()
tk.Label(app4, text="app4").grid()


def toggle():
    global toggle
    if toggle:
        app3.grid_forget()
        app4.grid()
        toggle = False

    else:
        app4.grid_forget()
        app3.grid()
        toggle = True


tk.Button(app1, text="click", command=toggle).grid(row=0, column=2)
app.mainloop()
```

If you are looking for a more dynamic way to do many frames you can use a list to hold all your frames and then iterate over that list.

```
import tkinter as tk


app = tk.Tk()


frame_list = []
frame_ndex = 0

for i in range(4):
    frame_list.append(tk.Frame(app))
    tk.Label(frame_list[-1], text='Frame {}'.format(i+1)).grid(row=1, column=0)

frame_list[frame_ndex].grid(row=1, column=0)


def toggle():
    global frame_ndex
    frame_list[frame_ndex].grid_forget()
    if frame_ndex+1 == len(frame_list):
        frame_ndex = 0
        frame_list[frame_ndex].grid(row=1, column=0)
    else:
        frame_ndex += 1
        frame_list[frame_ndex].grid(row=1, column=0)


tk.Button(app, text="click", command=toggle).grid(row=0, column=0)
app.mainloop()
```